# Securely delete Docker container or image

Tags: docker, security, shred

I need to securely delete all persistent data abount containers and docker images.
For example for a certain temporary container runned.

I mean secure deletion performed by tools like **shred** or **srm**, repeated overwriting zero ora random data on disk.

I suppose doing this manually could be deleterious and compromise docker's cache and layer system, at disk level everything should reside in the `/var/lib/docker/*` path but I'm not sure if running shred / srm in these paths could cause problems.

Comment: Would you shred the entire directory, or are you trying to only delete parts used by one container? How would you handle shared layers or images used by other containers? And can you stop the docker engine?

Comment: Repeated overwriting is not necessary on modern disks, one overwrite is enough. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10474/235964

Comment: what do you mean by modern ssd?